# Xamarin.Auth or IdentityModel + IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, identityserver4

Has anyone implemented IdentityServer4 authentication using Xamarin.Auth or IdentityModel?
I have tried using both IdentityModel and Xamarin.Auth and they both have missing features by the looks of it.

1. I can't seem to find a way to set response_type and response_mode in Xamarin.Auth's OAuth2Authenticator.
   But I like how I can open the native browser and listen to its completion/error events. Which in this case obviously is going into error for unauthorised client coz our IdentityServer4 in .Net Core requires the response_type and response_mode.
2. I can't seem to find a way to interact with the native browser using IdentityModel.I've read that the recommended way is using the external/native browser instead of a webview. Add to that, I get the disallowed_useragent error when using the webview trying to authenticate with google.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I ended up using Xamarin.Auth working with IdentityServer4 (in iOS at least for now) as Google Authentication (not android) was not happy with using a WebView with IdentityModel.

Notes for other developers who might be getting into similar issues with OAuth2Authenticator working with IdentityServer4, below is what happened and what worked for me:

1. Turns out response_type and response_mode were not required in our IdentityServer4 as we had defaults in the server.
2. My main issue was that I was getting a "client_unauthorized" error when Xamarin.Auth was requesting for the token because the RedirectUrl had a slash at the end whereas the configured RedirectUrl didn't.

   - My RedirectUrl didn't have a slash at the end when initialising OAuth2Authenticator
   - The extra slash at the end was magically added when I converted NSUrl to Uri inside the OpenUrl method in AppDelegate.cs before calling OneListAppContext.AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(url).
   - I guess it's a standard to have a slash before the question mark in the url query? If it is, I didn't know that because adding ?name=value in the url has always worked.
   - NSUrl coming from Safari in the OpenUrl method was myappname://oauth?code=1ec450f88737fcae0a2786699d5df24e3ca97a8b55c09da2ef13d58035821134...
   - New Uri after converting NSUrl to Uri was was myappname://oauth/?code=1ec450f88737fcae0a2786699d5df24e3ca97a8b55c09da2ef13d58035821134... (notice there's / after oauth)

The fix was pretty simple:
1. Change the configured RedirectUrl for my Client to have / at the end (e.g. myappname://oauth/)
2. Initialise the RedirectUrl in the Client for OAuth2Authentic to have / at the end  (e.g. myappname://oauth/)